# How to pass a dropdown menu value in a Ajax JsonList in order to save the values in the database?

Tags: php, html, mysql, json, ajax

I want to pass a dropdown value to a JsonList and save it to the DB. Json list is first sent to the controller file and then it'll call the relevant Model and class. It works when the input type is a text. But doesn't work when it's a dropdown. Below are my codes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="Psychlarity">
        <!--<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../images/favicon.png" type="image/png">-->

        <title>Psychlarity</title>
    </head>

    <body>

           <form method="POST" id="add_article_station"  data-toggle="validator">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                      <h4 class="panel-title"><i aria-hidden="true" class=""></i>Add New Question </h4>
                            <p>Use this form to add a new question to the system</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                 <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">

        <label>Age Category <span class="text-danger"></span></label>

     <select name="age" id="age" class="select-css" >

    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" >Select Age Category</option>

      <option value="t">Teen</option>
      <option value="a">Adult</option>
      <option value="e">Elder</option>
      <option value="">Any</option>

     </select>
   </div>

    <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">

        <label>Relationship Status Category <span class="text-danger"></span></label>

     <select name="RS" id="RS" class="select-css" >

     <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select Relationship Status Category</option>
      <option value="m">Married</option>
      <option value="n">Single</option>
      <option value="">Any</option>

     </select>
          </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">

        <label>Employement Status Category <span class="text-danger"></span></label>

     <select name="ES" id="ES" class="select-css" >

    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" >Select Employement Status Category</option>

      <option value="e">Employed</option>
      <option value="s">Student</option>
      <option value="u">Unemployed</option>
      <option value="">Any</option>



     </select>

                                                </div>

                                </div>  <br> <br>   
                                <div class="row pull-right">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
               <button class="btn btn-success btn-quirk btn-wide mr5">Submit</button>
              <button class="btn btn-quirk btn-wide btn-default" type="reset">Reset</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>   
</div></div></div></div></div></div></form></div></section>


        <script> 

         $("#add_article_station").validator().on('submit', function (event) {
                if (!event.isDefaultPrevented()) {
                    var formData = new FormData($('#add_article_station')[0]);
                    console.log(formData);
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "../../Controller/AddquestionController.php",
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: formData,
                        async: false,
                        success: function (data) {
                            try {
                                var json = JSON.parse(data)
                                if (json.code == 200) {
                                    window.location = "?msg=suc";
//                                alert(json.message);
                                } else {
                                    window.location = "?msg=err";
                                }
                            } catch (e) {
                                window.location = "?msg=err";
                            }

                        }, error: function (data) {
                            toastr.error("Error In Saving");
                        },
                        cache: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false
                    });
                }
                return false;
            });

            $(document).ready(function () {

                'use strict';
                function getParam(name) {
                    var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
                    if (results == null) {
                        return null;
                    } else {
                        return results[1] || 0;
                    }
                }

                $(function () {
                    if (getParam("msg") == "suc") {
                        toastr.success("Sucssfully saved.");
                    } else if (getParam("msg") == "err") {
                        toastr.success("Question saved.");
                    }
                });



        </script>
 <?php include '../includes/notificationJS.php'; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

The below is my Model where the DB query is.

```
public static function Addquestion($article, $logedUser) {
        if (TokenValidationModelClass::TokenValidate($logedUser)) {
            $dbh = dbconnect::Connection();
            $addquestionStmtStmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO questions
                                                (age_cat,employment_status,relationship_status)
                                                VALUES
                                                (:age_cat,:employment_status,:relationship_status);  ");

            $addquestionStmtStmt->bindParam(':age_cat', $article->age);
            $addquestionStmtStmt->bindParam(':employment_status', $article->es);
            $addquestionStmtStmt->bindParam(':relationship_status', $article->rs);


            if ($addquestionStmtStmt->execute()) {

                return HttpStatusMessageRest::getHttpStatusMessage(200);
            }
        }
        return HttpStatusMessageRest::getHttpStatusMessage(401);
    }
```

If anyone needs, below is the controller file of it.

```
<?php
include '../Model/session_include.php';
require_once("../Model/articleModelClass.php");

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {


    $data = (object) $_POST;
//    print_r($data);

    if (!empty($data)) {
        if (!empty($data->token)) {
            echo articleModelClass::Addquestion($data, $data->token);
        } else {
            $token = (object) $_SESSION;
//            print_r($token);
            echo articleModelClass::Addquestion($data, $token);
        }
    } else {
        $error["error"] = "Empty field.";
        echo json_encode($error);
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Which dropdown is missing? What is in $_POST

Comment: I cannot see a field with a `name` attribute set to `token`? Am I missing something

Comment: @RiggsFolly Supposed to be the 3 select options named as age, ES and RS. Not quite sure if those can be passed in a Jsonlist

Comment: @RiggsFolly If i make them texts instead of dropdowns, it actually works! The data is being passed and saved in the db